# Change innerHTML of multiple elements with least code possible

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have 6 buttons which, when clicked, each reveal a unique `div` below. I would simply like to change the `innerHTML` of said buttons upon being clicked. I can do this quite easily with one button with a unique ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
<label for="tab-one" id="one">Read More</label>
```

... 5 more checkboxes with corresponding labels.

```
var tabLabel = document.getElementById('one');
tabLabel.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.innerHTML=="Read More") {
    this.innerHTML = "Collapse";
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = "Read More";
  }
});
```

My question is how can I turn this block of JavaScript into something that will work for all 6 unique labels? This must be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers, but I used a simple `forEach` and gave each label the same `class`. Works perfectly. Shout out to @guest271314, whose answer also worked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
<label for="tab-one" class="one">Read More</label>

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.one');
elements.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.innerHTML=="Read More") {
      this.innerHTML = "Collapse";
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = "Read More";
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the pair of values at the element `data-*` attribute, which sets `.dataset` property as `JSON`, convert to JavaScript object at event handler, set `.textContent` to element of resulting array that is not current element, repeat procedure.

```js
onload = () => {
  for (let label of document.querySelectorAll("label[for]")) {
    label.onclick = () => {
      let [curr, next, {textContent}] = [...JSON.parse(label.dataset.t), label];
      label.textContent = textContent === curr ? next : curr;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="tab-one" id="one" data-t='["Read More", "Collapse"]'>Read More</label>
<label for="tab-two" id="two" data-t='["Read More", "Collapse"]'>Read More</label>
<label for="tab-three" id="three" data-t='["Read More", "Collapse"]'>Read More</label>
<label for="tab-four" id="four" data-t='["Read More", "Collapse"]'>Read More</label>
<label for="tab-five" id="five" data-t='["Read More", "Collapse"]'>Read More</label>
<label for="tab-six" id="six" data-t='["Read More", "Collapse"]'>Read More</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event agent, which is to attach the event hanlder to the six button's parent node.

The handler function should check which button is clicked actually. You can use the `event.target` property to realize this. And then change the target element(the clicked button)'s innerHTML.

```
var labelsParent = document.getElementById('one').parentNode;
labelsParent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (target.innerHTML=="Read More") {
    target.innerHTML = "Collapse";
  } else {
    target.innerHTML = "Read More";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo to @jackton, you can pass *this* as a parameter to event handler so that you don't need to retrieve the element by calling getElementById. The event handler can be implemented as:

```
var textArray = ['Collapse', 'Read More'...]; // put all your ping-pong text in this array

function onClick(el) {
    let idx = textArray.indexOf(el.innerHTML);
    el.innerHTML = textArray[idx % 2? idx - 1, idx + 1];
}
```